# Returning data in a particular timeframe and displaying it

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently I'm displaying all my data in a single day after comparing 2 of my tables like so:

```
with X as (
select l.*,
(select status_from from logs where logs.refno = l.refno and logs.logtime >= '2021-10-01' order by logs.logtime limit 1) logstat
from listings l
where l.added_date <= '2021-10-01'  
)
, Y as (select X.*, ifnull(X.logstat, X.status) stat from X)
SELECT
sum(case when status.text= 'Action' and Y.id is not null then 1 else 0 end) as `Action`,
sum(case when status.text= 'Draft' and Y.id is not null then 1 else 0 end) as `Draft`,
sum(case when status.text= 'Let' and Y.id is not null then 1 else 0 end) as `Let`,
sum(case when status.text= 'Sold' and Y.id is not null then 1 else 0 end) as `Sold`,
sum(case when status.text= 'Publish' and Y.id is not null then 1 else 0 end) as `Publish`
from status
left join Y on Y.stat = status.code
```

The logs table records all status changes for a product, but not the initial entry made in for the product, and the listings table displays what is the current status of the product as of today, and when this product was added to the table. Now to get the total data of a particular day, I'm using this statement which checks for everything in logs table that happened after selected date and everything in listings table that happened before the selected date. This returns the right output.

Now to get the output of dates 2021-10-01, 2021-10-02 and 2021-10-03, I have to get it by individually selecting all the dates. So I want a way where I can select the start date and end date and that will give me all the data in that timeframe and group them by their dates like so:

| Date | Publish | Action | Let | Sold | Draft |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-10-02 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 2021-10-03 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 2 |

Dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a4db2d923a1b48f2fc2291bc58ffb6cc

Comment: Provide sample data as online fiddle or CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO script which matches shown desired output with needed data range condition (some data out of the range must exist too).

Comment: @Akina Fiddle provided

Comment: *Fiddle provided* And how does the data in this fiddle correlates with **shown desired output**?

Comment: @Akina So as of now in my fiddle the date is 2021-10-01 which shows the same output as that of the table I have provided in the question. If you were to change that date to 2021-10-02 it would again show the output that is there of 2021-10-02 in my table and so on. Now here I can only get the data for 1 day, but I want to show it like my table where user selects between 2 dates and it shows all the outputs